# Forward CMake BOOL to C++

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to be able to set a bunch of boolean flags when calling CMake, that are later used in C++ code. Something like:

```
set(DEBUG_ENABLE false CACHE BOOL "enable debugging")
target_compile_definitions(target PRIVATE DEBUG_ENABLE=${DEBUG_ENABLE})
```

This actually works fine and produces something equivalent to:

```
#define DEBUG_ENABLE false
```

However, the the native CMake literals for `BOOL`s are `ON`/`OFF` and tools like the CMake GUI will use those values, resulting in a define that doesn't work well in C++:

```
#define DEBUG_ENABLE OFF
```

What is the best way to forward such a boolean variable from CMake to C++?

I can think of a few things:

- Conversion function in CMake, resulting in three lines per boolean value
- Use `STRING` instead of `BOOL`
- Make it work in C++: `#define ON true`

None of these options seem particularly great to me.

Comment: You could also add the `#defines` from CMake: `add_compile_definitions(ON=1)`, `add_compile_definitions(OFF=0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `configure_file`.  It won't get you a C++ `bool` directly, but it's something that will actually scale over time.

You'll need to make a config file template for cmake to modify, in this example `config.hpp.in`.

```
#cmakedefine01 DEBUG_ENABLE
```

Next, add a `configure_file` line to your `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
configure_file(config.hpp.in "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/config.hpp")
```

Any variable in the config template will be replaced with either 0/1 depending on the value in cmake.

Working output:

```
(after configuring)
$ cat config.hpp 
#define DEBUG_ENABLE 0

$ cmake -DDEBUG_ENABLE=ON .
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/so/cmake-bool/build
$ cat config.hpp 
#define DEBUG_ENABLE 1
```

This also completely removes the need for your `target_compile_definitions` line, provided you `#include "config.hpp"` in the appropriate places.